# modify elements of inflated view used as ListView header.

Tags: android

I have a list view with a custom adapter that I am attaching and It needs to have a header with some modifiable information in it. I have created an xml layout for the header, and when its applied everything displayes correctly. But when I try to reference the elements in the header view and set there contents, I receive a Resource not found exception. The exception is specifically thrown at "name.setText(task.getName());". I presume it would be thrown at each of the 3 elements I reference If it go that far.

What is the correct way to do this? Are the resources im referencing not in scope? How can I modify them correctly?

The onCreate of my activity containing the list looks like what is below:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.taskview);

    Object sTask = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("task");

    TaskNode task = (TaskNode)sTask;


    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null); 

    TextView name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.hname);
    TextView description = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.hdescription);
    TextView completion = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.hcompletion);

    name.setText(task.getName());
    description.setText(task.getDescription());
    completion.setText(task.completion());


    taskList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taskList);

    taskList.addHeaderView(header); 

    TaskViewListItem adapter = new TaskViewListItem(this, getApplicationContext(), task);

    taskList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: code looks good. What exception do you get?

Comment: 07-13 01:04:18.496: E/AndroidRuntime(9270): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x19

Comment: this excption means that one from getName, getDescription or completation in returning an int (or a number), am I wrong?

Comment: Yep, completion will return an int. I feel quite stupid. solved with "Integer.toString()".

Comment: @gh123man post the entire stacktrace. if possible point out the line where the exception occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception you get one from `getName()`, `getDescription()` and `completation()` is returning a numeric value. When you call setText with an int value android will lookup inside R in order to find the String with the id you provide as parameter to `setText`. If a String with that id does not exist the `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` exception will be thrown. You can get the String representation of a number with:

```
String value = String.valueOf(numericValue);
```